# How to call Enum individual methods?

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum that might look like the one below. My goal is to have an `enum` with some common methods (I enforced this by adding an abstract method) and some "enum value individual" methods.

The following code compiles:

```
public enum MyEnum {

    VALUE {
        @Override
        public void syso() {
            System.out.println("VALUE syso");
        }
    },

    SPECIAL_VALUE {
        @Override
        public void syso() {
            System.out.println("SPECIAL_VALUE syso");
        }

        public void sayHello() {
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }
    };

    public abstract void syso();

    public static void main(String... args) {
        MyEnum.VALUE.syso();
        MyEnum.SPECIAL_VALUE.syso();
    }

}
```

Running this results in the following being printed:

```
VALUE syso
SPECIAL_VALUE syso
```

However trying to call `sayHello()`, which I defined in `SPECIAL_VALUE`, does not work.

Adding the following to the main method, does not compile anymore:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    MyEnum.SPECIAL_VALUE.sayHello(); // does not work
}
```

Why is that? It seems perfectly fine to me, but the method cannot be found. Is there any way to invoke this method? Maybe via reflection?

I would like to avoid making this method abstract as well, because it does not make sense for any other enum values. I also cannot `extend` this enum and add this special method, while inheriting the common ones. I would also like to avoid adding some kind of singleton class to "simulate" this.

Is it anyhow possible to run this? If not, what would be my best alternative?

Comment: you will definitly be able to call it via reflection

Comment: Don't declare method abstract, just make it empty. And in `SPECIAL_VALUE` override it. I think it may be possible to use reflection, but why?

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov Implementing it in an empty way would also result in me being able to call `MyEnum.VALUE.sayHello()`, which would not do anything. That doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: The reason is given in the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9): `Instance methods declared in enum class bodies may be invoked outside the enclosing enum type only if they override accessible methods in the enclosing enum type (§8.4.8).`

Comment: @noone You could still throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` - IMHO a cleaner design than using reflection

Comment: @Andreas Okay, that explains why it does not compile.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> *Why is that?*

The reason is given in the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9):

> **8.9.1. Enum Constants**
>
> ...
>
> Instance methods declared in enum class bodies may be invoked outside the enclosing enum type **only if they override accessible methods in the enclosing enum type (§8.4.8)**.

> *Is there any way to invoke this method? Maybe via reflection?*

Given the above constraint, reflection is the only alternative if you do not want to expose the method in the enclosing enum class. Each enum constant is created as an inner class, like `MyEnum$1` and `MyEnum$2` in your example. Thus, you can retrieve the `Class` through the constant's `getClass()` method and then call your method through reflection (exception handling omitted):

```
...
Class c = MyEnum.SPECIAL_VALUE.getClass();
Method m = c.getMethod("sayHello");
m.invoke(MyEnum.SPECIAL_VALUE);
...
```

I would most likely try to avoid reflection and expose the method in the enum class, and let it throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`:

```
...
public void sayHello() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
...
```

This at least catches unintended calls during runtime - it still does not allow the compiler to catch them during compile time, but neither does the reflection approach.

Comment: Thanks, I think this explains it well enough. I think I'll go with your solution implementing it by throwing an `UnsupportedOperationException` and overriding that in `SPECIAL_VALUE`. I still don't understand the reason behind this statement in the JLS though.

Comment: @noone What the JLS says makes sense if you think about the fact that the only public interface enums have is the one declared by the enum class itself, which means that the compiler has no way of knowing about "special" methods you declare in only one/some of your constants in client code. In other situations where you're working with "normal" classes, you'd get around this by downcasting, but since enums implemented in that particular style are anonymous classes, you can't perform such a cast (without reflection (and I'm not even sure if that could work)).

Comment: Any reason why java doesn't warn or throw error on declaring these "special" public methods inside enum instances when the same method is not exposed by redeclaring in the parent enum?

Answer (score 1):

Because `SPECIAL_VALUE` is an instance of `enum` and `enum` has only method `syso()`.you are calling

Here is the same thing with classes:

```
interface Foo {

        Foo inst1 = new Foo() {
            @Override
            public void doFoo() {
            }

            public void doAnonymous() {

            }
        };
        void doFoo();
    }
```

You cannot call method doAnonymous() like Foo.inst1.doAnonymous() and you are able to access the doAnonymous only via reflection

Comment: Well, I'm not saying `MyEnum.sayHello()`, I'm explictly saying `MyEnum.SPECIAL_VALUE.sayHello()`. So in contrast to your code I still give the compiler at least a hint about the "subtype". MyEnum.SPECIAL_VALUE doesn't feel like an "anonymous" subtype, since I explicitly give it a name.

Comment: Well, yeah, but compiler treats it as an instance of MyEnum. And MyEnum doesn't have a method sayHello().

Comment: Yeah, it definetely seems to be that way. The Java compiler devs were probably just too lazy to make this work. :)